# Plot changes in derivatives of line plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to replicate this plot in matplotlib using my data i.e. a line graph with vertical lines depicting the changes where positive, negative or flat derivative changes occur.

[image]

I have created a pandas dataframe with the diff as the derivative and a segment change everytime there is an arbitray break in the derivative, I want to plot lat on the y axis with time on the x axis and a vline wherever there is a break in the segment number.

```
     lat                time  trip_id     diff  shifted    Segment
-7.11559 2015-12-16 21:53:47    17601  0.00446  0.00003        0
-7.11559 2015-12-16 21:53:45    17601  0.00000  0.00446        1
-7.11563 2015-12-16 21:53:41    17601 -0.00004  0.00000        2
-7.11551 2015-12-16 21:48:29    17601  0.00012 -0.00004        2
-7.11548 2015-12-16 21:48:27    17601  0.00003  0.00012        2
-7.11545 2015-12-16 21:48:26    17601  0.00003  0.00003        2
-7.11539 2015-12-16 21:48:25    17601  0.00006  0.00003        2
-7.11548 2015-12-16 21:43:17    17601 -0.00009  0.00006        2
-7.11545 2015-12-16 21:43:15    17601  0.00003 -0.00009        2
-7.11545 2015-12-16 21:43:13    17601  0.00000  0.00003        3
-7.11542 2015-12-16 21:43:12    17601  0.00003  0.00000        4
```

I can plot the first 2 easily enough with `df.plot(x='time',y='lat')`. However I'm struggling on the logic about how to add the vline into a time axis and what parameters to pass to the matplotlib vline. Any help or hints would be most appreciated.

UPDATE 1.

I have written this code which in my mind should work to solve this problem.

```
plotList=[]
breaker = pd.unique(df.Segment.ravel())
def pullLine(row):
    for i in breaker: 
        if any(row['Segment']) == i:
            plotList.append(row['time'])
# breaker is a list of unique segment numbers, this for loop should loop over breaker and then where the first instance of i == the segment number appending the time value to the list 
pullLine(df)
print plotList

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(x='Segment',y='lat')
# this loops over `plotList` and should plot a `axvline` at each instance.
for i in plotList:
    plt.axvline(x = i,linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

However, running the code as above i'm getting `KeyError: 0` on the `plt.axvline`. If I manually plug a date into the line `plt.axvline(x = '2015-12-24 21:51:45')` I get `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-12-24 21:51:45`.

Any ideas on how to a) solve this or b) print a vline with a timeseries on the x axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem. It works but just needs some tweaking to smooth out all the little derivative changes in the line. Any additions or improvements welcome.

```
previous = None
segnumber = 0

def func(row):
   global segnumber
    previous = row['shifted']
    if row['diff'] > 0:
        if previous < -0.5 or previous == 0:
            segnumber = segnumber + 1
        return segnumber
    elif row['diff'] == 0:
        if previous < -0.5 or previous > 0.5:
            segnumber = segnumber + 1
        return segnumber
    elif row['diff'] < 0:
        if previous > 0.5 or previous == 0:
            segnumber = segnumber + 1
        return segnumber

df['Segment'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
df['dup'] = df.duplicated('Segment')

plotList = df.loc[df['dup'] == False, 'time'].tolist()

ax = df.plot(x='time',y='lat')
for i in plotList:
    plt.axvline(x=i)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

```
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
ax.add_collections(matplotlib.collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
            x, ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, where=[your condition],
            facecolor='red', alpha=0.25)
```

See [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/span_regions.html) for more detailed examples.